# With Firebase is using CustomUserClaims a good idea to give access to paying users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

In my app using Firebase as back-end, I wanted to implement a new feature based on Firebase Storage to allow my users to save some files.

Knowing that my app can be accessed only by people who are paying a subscription, I'm already filtering the access to Firestore (used in my project to store user data) via a document that stores if the subscrition is valid or not and this is filtered by the Firestore security rules.

I saw that there is no linkage between Firestore and Storage, so I can't in the Storage security rules read my Firestore documents. So I had the idea to use CustomClaims to add to the Auth token an attribute if the subscription is valid or not.

After tinkering a bit with it, I noticed and checked that it takes up to an hour to client to have a refreshed token. Since my app follow roughtly this workflow:

[image: Workflow]

I don't think that is a good user experience to wait for an hour to have access to a service the user just paid.

Is there something I didn't see ? Is there a way to circumvent this problem ? Is there an other way to have a refresh token than to force the user to logout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the ID token to be refreshed with `currentUser.getIdToken(true)` with the JS SDK. There are similar methods for the other Client SDKs.

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client) for more details.

Comment: That was indeed the right thing to do, thank you !